# How to pass decimal as a value when creating a PySpark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, types, apache-spark-sql, decimal

I want to create a dummy dataframe with one row which has Decimal values in it. But when do so it automatically converts it to a double. I want the data type to be Decimal(18,2) or etc.

```
dummy_row = spark.createDataFrame([(0,-1,'missing','missing',0.0],df.columns)
```

I want the schema to be

```
unique_id:integer
line_id:long
line_name:string
line_type:string
pct:decimal(18,5)
```

But I get

```
unique_id:integer
line_id:long
line_name:string
line_type:string
pct:double
```

How do I cast the double to decimal type in PySpark?

Comment: If you want 5 decimal only for representation, you can use [format_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.format_number) otherwise you have to use double as you said

Comment: Just cast it to the type you want: `dummy_row.withColumn("pct", col("pct").cast(DecimalType(18,2)))` where you have to import `col` from `pyspark.sql.functions` and `DecimalType` from `pyspark.sql.Types`.

Comment: @pault I want to pass it as a decimal when creating the data frame. Is withColumn the only way to go about it i.e. after creating the data frame?

Comment: @ggeop i want the schema to represent that column as data type decimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways.

My preferred way is to **`cast` decimal type** after the dataframe is created.
*It is safest to provide values as strings.*

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("92.34567890123456789", )], ["col_1"])
df = df.withColumn("col_1", F.col("col_1").cast("decimal(30,20)"))

df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
#  +-----------------------+
#  |col_1                  |
#  +-----------------------+
#  |92.34567890123456789000|
#  +-----------------------+
#
#  root
#   |-- col_1: decimal(30,20) (nullable = true)
```

*If values were provided as numbers, Python may "truncate" your values, because it would first create [double precision floating point numbers](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) (16-17 significant digits) out of what was provided in the code. Note how the last digits `789` would disappear:*

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(92.34567890123456789, )], ["col_1"])
df = df.withColumn("col_2", F.col("col_1").cast("decimal(30,20)"))

df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
#  +-----------------+-----------------------+
#  |col_1            |col_2                  |
#  +-----------------+-----------------------+
#  |92.34567890123456|92.34567890123456000000|
#  +-----------------+-----------------------+
#
#  root
#   |-- col_1: double (nullable = true)
#   |-- col_2: decimal(30,20) (nullable = true)
```

The other way is to **create decimal numbers** beforehand.

```
from decimal import Context
dec_number = Context(prec=38).create_decimal('92.34567890123456789')
df = spark.createDataFrame([(dec_number, )], 'col_1 decimal(30,20)')

df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
#  +-----------------------+
#  |col_1                  |
#  +-----------------------+
#  |92.34567890123456789000|
#  +-----------------------+
#
#  root
#   |-- col_1: decimal(30,20) (nullable = true)
```

<sup>`38` is the maximum decimal precision which is supported in Spark.</sup>

---

So, in your case you could:

1.1. - create dataframe from scratch - casting to decimal after df is created

```
dummy_row = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, -1, 'missing', 'missing', '0.0')],
    "unique_id:int, line_id:long, line_name:string, line_type:string, pct:string")
dummy_row = dummy_row.withColumn("pct", F.col("pct").cast("decimal(18,5)"))

dummy_row.show(truncate=False)
dummy_row.printSchema()
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |unique_id|line_id|line_name|line_type|pct    |
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |0        |-1     |missing  |missing  |0.00000|
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#
#  root
#   |-- unique_id: integer (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_id: long (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_name: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_type: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- pct: decimal(18,5) (nullable = true)
```

1.2. - create dataframe from scratch - using Python's `decimal` module

```
from decimal import Context
dec_number = Context(prec=38).create_decimal('0.0')
dummy_row = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(0, -1, 'missing', 'missing', dec_number)],
    "unique_id:int, line_id:long, line_name:string, line_type:string, pct:decimal(18,5)")

dummy_row.show(truncate=False)
dummy_row.printSchema()
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |unique_id|line_id|line_name|line_type|pct    |
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |0        |-1     |missing  |missing  |0.00000|
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#
#  root
#   |-- unique_id: integer (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_id: long (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_name: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_type: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- pct: decimal(18,5) (nullable = true)
```

2.1. - borrow schema from existing df (it seems you originally wanted this) - casting to decimal after df is created

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [],
    "unique_id:int, line_id:long, line_name:string, line_type:string, pct:decimal(18,5)")
dummy_row = spark.createDataFrame([(0, -1, 'missing', 'missing', '0.0')], df.columns)
dummy_row = dummy_row.withColumn("pct", F.col("pct").cast("decimal(18,5)"))

dummy_row.show(truncate=False)
dummy_row.printSchema()
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |unique_id|line_id|line_name|line_type|pct    |
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |0        |-1     |missing  |missing  |0.00000|
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  
#  root
#   |-- unique_id: long (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_id: long (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_name: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_type: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- pct: decimal(18,5) (nullable = true)
```

2.2. - borrow schema from existing df (it seems you originally wanted this) - using Python's `decimal` module

```
from decimal import Context
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [],
    "unique_id:int, line_id:long, line_name:string, line_type:string, pct:decimal(18,5)")
dec_number = Context(prec=38).create_decimal('0.0')
dummy_row = spark.createDataFrame([(0, -1, 'missing', 'missing', dec_number)], df.schema)

dummy_row.show(truncate=False)
dummy_row.printSchema()
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |unique_id|line_id|line_name|line_type|pct    |
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#  |0        |-1     |missing  |missing  |0.00000|
#  +---------+-------+---------+---------+-------+
#
#  root
#   |-- unique_id: integer (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_id: long (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_name: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- line_type: string (nullable = true)
#   |-- pct: decimal(18,5) (nullable = true)
```

Comment: So many great examples novices like me can draw upon from this answer. Thank you